# Algorithm complexity of this program is O(n) or O(n^3)?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I am very much confuse that why complexity of this program is O(n)?

```
 int j = 0;
 int i;
 For (i = 0; i < n, i++) // O(n)
 {
      For (i = 0; i < n, i++)//O(n)
      {
        While (j < n)// O(n)
       {
        Statement; j++;
       }
   }    
 }
```

I am totally new to Algorithms. Any help and explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all please replace the image with text (source code). Second, what is your version? Why do you think it should be $O(n^3)$ and not $O(n^)$? Please include it in your post.

Comment: @fade2black I tried to type text but it gets jumbled up. I don't know how to use editor, I am completely new here. And how I thought it is O(n^3) , there are three loops, so obvious it is O(n^3)

Comment: In fact $O(n^3)$ is not a wrong answer, but $O(n)$ is tighter bound. Three loops does not necessary imply cubic time. Please pay attention to variables used in the for-loops. In particular, is it true that the outermost for-loop always runs $n$ times? How many times is `j++` invoked?

Comment: @fade2black sorry to say, I tried. Inner loop runs n times. Outer For loop will executed once and later i will be incremented one more time before it get terminated. J++ runs n times, only once. But I want some concrete answer :/

Comment: The inner for-loop starts from $i=0$ and runs until $i=n$.`Statement; j++` is executed $n$ times for only $i=0$ and never executed for $i>0$. The outer for-loop runs only once for $i=0$. You could observe it by running this code.

Comment: So, complexity would be O(n^2)?

Comment: `Statement; j++` is invoked $n$ times (total!), and the second for-loop increments $i$ $n$ times (total!), and the outer for-loop increments $i$ only once after which it quits since $i$ reaches $n$ (by the second for-loop). This gives $n+n +1= 2n+1$ which is $O(n)$.

Comment: Take n=5 and execute the algorithm on paper, step by step. Observe.

Comment: @fade2black I wanted to say O (n) but editor says I can edit only after 5 mins. I already understand, Thanks!!!

Comment: @Raphael sure I will :)

Comment: @Raphael How can you mark this question as duplicate? It is a specific question. You can't link my specific question to your generalized question. It is against guidelines.

Comment: @ubhatt Your question contains little but code and the prompt "please analyse for me". That's what we call a problem dump. And since the reference question I link explains in great detail how to deal with loops, it *is* a duplicate. Now, this may be different if you included your previous attempts and thoughts in the question, and ask an *actual*, narrow question. But you don't. So a duplicate it is. (And trust me, I'm very aware of the guidelines.)

Comment: I'll just give you a hint: There are three loops in your code. And two of them are cleverly designed to convince an inexperienced programmer that they are doing something totally different from what they are _actually_ doing. Examine the code very carefully. You should _twice_ say to yourself "NOW I get what it does. This was hidden really cleverly". Then the answer to your question is really simple.